# SoundCloud User info api

Tags: soundcloud

Are there anyway to get user cover photo on soundcloud ?
I am trying to use this API :
`http://api.soundcloud.com/users/`
, but it just returns user avatar.

Comment: whats the difference between avatar and 'user cover photo'?

Comment: The cover photo is the big header photo like Facebook one, you can change the default one and upload a new one from the top right when you hover on the top part a button will appear "update photo".

Answer (score 1):

The Profile Header Background Image is not API driven, it is an asset returned from the CDN on an HTTP request for the profile page URL.

I've tested this by sniffing the requests on mobile and desktop browsers.  Getting that image from the API is not supported at this time.

One hint that proves this (without sniffing the requests) is that the mobile site and apps do not show or use this image at all.

Comment: I reached to the same result, thank you for your effort